# Why does HttpRequest return ProgressEvent error in Dart

Tags: http, dart

I want to make a http call in dart, but some sites when i tried returns a ProgressEvent error and somes not. I cannot understand it.

[dartpad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnPEI.png)

```dart
import 'dart:html';
void main() async {
  print(await HttpRequest.getString('https://swapi.co/api/people/1'));
}
```

I expect the output of

```
{
"name": "Luke Skywalker",
"height": "172",
"mass": "77",
"hair_color": "blond",
"skin_color": "fair",
"eye_color": "blue",
"birth_year": "19BBY",
"gender": "male",
"homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
"films":[
"https://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
"https://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
"https://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
"https://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
"https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
],
"species":[
"https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
],
"vehicles":[
"https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/",
"https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
],
"starships":[
"https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/",
"https://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"
],
"created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
"edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
"url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
}
```

but the return is

```
Uncaught Error: Instance of 'ProgressEvent'
```

In my tests it depends of the url: if i try with the same code, but the url is: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, the json is successfully loaded.
[example json returns correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVETH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set allow CORS?
I had the same problem with my REST server, I allowed CORS origins and it worked!
You can use the site: https://www.test-cors.org/
Use this page to test CORS requests.